# iTunes 11 on Snow Leopard

Tags: itunes, snow-leopard

Where can I download iTunes 11? I have an older Mac, max OS X 10.6.8 and have problems with synchronising iPhone iOS8 and iPad iOS7 with iTunes 11.4 (the latest version on this OS X-system for this old Mac ;). Synchronise stays grey. So I searched and searched for answers. On the AppleSupport I found a solution: trash iTunes 11, empty the trash, restart, reinstall iTunes 11. Now I can't find iTunes 11 on the web(site) to reinstall.

Comment: Can you add a link to the Apple support page?

Comment: Thank you very much. The give link works! I searched but didn't found. I hope the synchronise-problems will be solved now :-))) @suit4 and JefeJefeJefe Greetz, Chris Antwerp Belgium

Answer (score 2):

There is a support page on Apples website:
http://support.apple.com/downloads/#itunes

Answer (score 0):

This link should help you.
http://support.apple.com/downloads/#itunes

At least on my machine, it's showing me a list of all older versions for many OSes.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of the other answer.